# C++: Extract Session token from cURL connection

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I have used [this code example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplessl.html) successfully. Running this code returns to stdout:

```
{"sessionToken": <some string>,"loginStatus":"SUCCESS"}
```

I need to have the sessionToken string for the following requests I need to made, thus including cookie in http headers won't work for me.

I could redirect stdout to a pipe and read from there but I am looking for a more efficient, native libcurl/C++ way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you setup a write callback for libcurl and receive the response directly into a memory buffer instead and then you parse that to extract what you need after the request has completed.

The [getinmemory libcurl examples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) shows one way to receive data directly into a memory buffer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. 
Thank you very much Daniel. Congratulations for the great library by the way.
PS: There is some issue with the code example, since I had to replace realloc with malloc inside WriteMemoryCallback in order to avoid segmentation fault.